# Why does async await not work in this function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

This might be a bit of a beginner question, but I can't figure this out:

I'm doing an asyncronous database call in which I want to get an object from the database and asign this object to the window object (window.naamID).

Next I want to run a function where I use the object assinged to the window object (making it global) and use it as a database query (.where("Vraagsteller", "==", naamID)).

The problem, of course, is that the second function starts running before the first function has fnished (because of it's asyncronous nature).

I wanted to overcome this problem by wrapping the second function in a syncronous function and await the first function.

This doesn't seem the work. The console says the object asigned to the window object is undefined.

[image: Snapshot of console log]

This is the code:

```
 function constructAuthMenu(){
auth.onAuthStateChanged(User =>{

    const userRef = db.collection("Vitaminders")
    .doc(User.uid);
    userRef.get()
    .then(function(doc) {

        const naamID = doc.data().Gebruikersnaam;
        const ID = doc.data().ID
        const naam = naamID.replace(ID, "")
        const profilePic = doc.data().Profielfoto

        window.naamID = naamID
     });
  });
}; 

constructAuthMenu()

 async function getNewReactions(){

        await constructAuthMenu()

      db.collectionGroup("Reactions")
      .where("Vraagsteller", "==", naamID)
      .where("New", "==", 
       "Yes").get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

       *Do stuff*

   });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Or doesn't async await work like this?

Comment: Your code is a bit difficult to follow, what does `constructMenuFunction` refer to?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I was tinkering with the code before I posted this question here. I tried to bind the function to a variable (const constructMenuFunction = constructAuthMenu()).  I forgot to change the code in the async function back to await constructAuthMenu(). I edited the post.

Comment: `auth.onAuthStateChanged` presumably fires every time the auth state changes. You can't really track this with promises because they deal with things which happen **once** and that sounds like something that can happen multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `constructMenuFunction` actually exists elsewhere in your code, and returns a Promise, then your problem is that you're missing parentheses on your function call: `await constructMenuFunction();`

If `constructMenuFunction` does not exist elsewhere in your code, and the first function preceding the async function is actually what you wish to invoke, your problem is that the first function does not return a Promise and your async function invokes the wrong method and without parentheses.

```
async function constructAuthMenu() {
  return await auth.onAuthStateChanged(async User => {
    try {
      const userRef = db.collection("Vitaminders").doc(User.uid);
      const doc = await userRef.get();
      const naamID = doc.data().Gebruikersnaam;
      const ID = doc.data().ID;
      const naam = naamID.replace(ID, "");
      const profilePic = doc.data().Profielfoto;
      return naamID;
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
 });
};
```

Comment: There's a **lot** more wrong with the code then that

Comment: Yes, but the question was "how does async/await work" and it only works if you actually invoke the asynchronous function you're awaiting.

Comment: It only works if you `await` a promise. `constructMenuFunction` doesn't even exist, and `constructAuthMenu` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Sorry for assuming `constructMenuFunction` existed elsewhere in the code? 

Comment: Reading the text of the question implies that `constructMenuFunction ` was a typo for `constructAuthMenu` and that brings us back to the problem that it doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Except that `constructAuthMenu` is being invoked prior to the definition of the async function, and is actually irrelevant to the code the OP is having problems with.

Comment: I think the OP is completely misunderstanding how `await` works and is trying to await the already invoked function.

Comment: That's a reasonable interpretation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the confusion.. I was tinkering with the code before I posted this question here. I tried to bind the function to a variable (const constructMenuFunction = constructAuthMenu()).  I forgot to change the code in the async function back to await constructAuthMenu(). I edited the post. The question remains: why doesn't the constructAuthMenu function return a promise, since the database call is a asyncronous process?

Comment: Because `constructAuthMenu` itself doesn't return anything. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @selfagency